# Is there a way to toggle class on React Button but un toggle other buttons so the one clicked is active?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to toggle a button class in React in a button group, so for example when one button is clicked the others are then not active. I know it can be done via `setState`. So far I have implemented it so it works but When I add more buttons they don't toggle the other ones off, is there a way to flag the active one and unflag the other buttons?

original storybook component

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.scss';

interface ButtonProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    onClick?: (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
    variant: string | string;
    className?: string | string;
}

const Button: React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = (props: ButtonProps) => {
    return (
        <button type="button" onClick={props.onClick} className={`btn-${props.variant}`}>{props.children}</button>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

code so far

```
const ActiveBtn: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

    const [active, setActive] = React.useState<boolean>(true)
    const handleClick = () => setActive(toggle => !toggle)
    return (
        <>
        <Button variant={active ? 'tertiary' : 'tertiary-active'} onClick={handleClick}>{active ? '.Active' : 'Active'}</Button>
        </>
    )
}
```

then in my component I use as:

```
<ActiveBtn />
```

Any idea's? is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You may have to lift up the state to the container which hosts the buttons and track/decide which is active button

Comment: Can you elaborate? do you mean the bubbling of events? event delegation?

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this might be like below;

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import React, { FC, useState, MouseEvent } from 'react'

const ActiveBtn: FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState<string>('')

  const handleClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    const { id } = event.target as HTMLInputElement
    setActive(id)
  }

  const isActive = (id: string) => active === id

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        id="button1"
        onClick={handleClick}
        variant={isActive('button1') ? 'tertiary' : 'tertiary-active'}
      >
        {isActive('button1') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'}
      </Button>

      <Button
        id="button2"
        onClick={handleClick}
        variant={isActive('button2') ? 'tertiary' : 'tertiary-active'}
      >
        {isActive('button2') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'}
      </Button>

      <Button
        id="button3"
        onClick={handleClick}
        variant={isActive('button3') ? 'tertiary' : 'tertiary-active'}
      >
        {isActive('button3') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'}
      </Button>

      <Button
        id="button4"
        onClick={handleClick}
        variant={isActive('button4') ? 'tertiary' : 'tertiary-active'}
      >
        {isActive('button4') ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'}
      </Button>
    </>
  )
}

export default ActiveBtn
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the original component, the code you suggested above flags errors on the onClick `Object is possibly 'null'.` and `Type '(event: Event) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': cancelBubble, composed, returnValue, srcElement, and 7 more.`

Comment: Sorry about that @Sole... I just updated the answer with the correct type for the click event.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to know the state outside of the button you can keep track of the button state inside the button"

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Button.scss";

const Button = (props) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(true);
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        setIsActive(!isActive);
        props.onClick();
      }}
      className={isActive ? props.isActiveClass : props.isInactiveClass}>
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

then just pass it the state and the classes you want it to have from the parent as:

```
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    console.log("my lil function");
  }}
  isActiveClass={"btn-tertiary-active"}
  isInactiveClass={"btn-tertiary"}
/>;
```

Comment: How would this work with a group of buttons?

Comment: Depends on what you mean? you can use the same button component and specify styles for each buttons active and inactive state, and with the passed down function from the parent you can choose to alter the view/state of something else